# how to set up a multi-domain multi-language in symfony2

Tags: symfony, bundle, locale, multisite

I am working on a project that is on expansion and needs to support multi-domain and multi-language.

I find that the way the standard routing is managed does not cover in an efficient way the project needs.

I found this: https://github.com/alexandresalome/multisite-bundle

It's find it good but I see the following drawbacks: 
  1) The bundle has not really much movement 
  2) The routing is set up at Controller/annotation level instead of yml file, what makes project hard to maintain.

Do you know any bundle/strategy based on symfony2 for this need? thanks a lot !!!

Comment: what you want to do is pretty easy, in short, let several virtualhosts point to the symfony app and in routing make a hostname condition

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't solve the problem.

This is my scenario:

I have a parameter where I set up several hosts: landing_hosts, separated by “|”

I have some landings, that are only valid for those hosts, routing: landings

When a request comes, I can’t see any way to dynamically set the current host for the default => hosts entry.

I am forced to specify one, that is %domain%. This works this way because there is a cached file appDevUrlGenerator.php that is created at first time website is visited or ran the command app/cache cache:clear.

**If I visit a landing page as host2, the urls and paths created inside twig templates will follow the  hosts1 instead hosts2, and this is not valid.**

// parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    landing_hosts: host1|host2
    main_host: host1
```

// routing.yml

```
landings:
    host: "{hosts}"
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: FrontendBundle:Landings:index }
    requirements:
       hosts: %landing_hosts%
    defaults: 
      hosts: %main_host%
```